# Package code_transformers has no versions that match

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to set up a new environment for a codebase that I inherited which uses AngularDart. The original developer left 4 years ago so I don't have access to his working environment. I'm new to Dart so perhaps this is an easy answer but in digging around I haven't found a solution. This is an old version of AngularDart as well so I'm not sure if that plays a part but I can't upgrade that at this time.

I'm currently using Dart **1.24.3** on my system. Building from the command line or via Eclipse yields the same results.

My `pubspec.yaml` only contains:

```
name: <app name>
description: <app description>
dependencies:
  angular: 0.14.0
transformers:
- angular:
    html_files: web/index.html
```

Since this is a new environment there's no packages file so I'm trying to run a `pub get` and receiving the following error.

```
Pub get failed, [1] Resolving dependencies...
Package code_transformers has no versions that match >=0.1.4+2 <0.2.0 derived from:
- angular 0.14.0 depends on version >=0.1.4+2 <0.2.0
```

If I run `pub get --trace` then this additional info is in the log for the three versions that do fall into that range (the others just give the usual non-matching message):

```
...
version 0.2.0+3 of code_transformers doesn't match >=0.1.4+2 <0.2.0:
   angular 0.14.0 from hosted -> code_transformers >=0.1.4+2 <0.2.0 from hosted (code_transformers)

inconsistent constraints on barback:
   code_transformers 0.1.6 from hosted -> barback >=0.11.0 <0.15.0 from hosted (barback)
   angular 0.14.0 from hosted -> barback >=0.13.0 <0.17.0 from hosted (barback)
   pub itself -> barback >=0.15.0 <0.15.3 from hosted (barback)

inconsistent constraints on barback:
   code_transformers 0.1.5 from hosted -> barback >=0.11.0 <0.15.0 from hosted (barback)
   angular 0.14.0 from hosted -> barback >=0.13.0 <0.17.0 from hosted (barback)
   pub itself -> barback >=0.15.0 <0.15.3 from hosted (barback)

inconsistent constraints on barback:
   code_transformers 0.1.4+2 from hosted -> barback >=0.11.0 <0.15.0 from hosted (barback)
   angular 0.14.0 from hosted -> barback >=0.13.0 <0.17.0 from hosted (barback)
   pub itself -> barback >=0.15.0 <0.15.3 from hosted (barback)

version 0.1.4+1 of code_transformers doesn't match >=0.1.4+2 <0.2.0:
   angular 0.14.0 from hosted -> code_transformers >=0.1.4+2 <0.2.0 from hosted (code_transformers)
...
```

Based on a few posts/articles I have tried a number of things but a common one I found is adding this to the `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependency_overrides:
   code_transformers: '>=0.2.0 <0.3.0'
```

but that ends up creating a new error so I think this is probably just getting into a deeper dependency hell. Adjusting the override versions ends up with this error regardless of the range I specify.

```
Resolving dependencies...
Warning: You are using these overridden dependencies:
! code_transformers 0.2.9+3
Got dependencies!
Precompiling dependencies...
Loading source assets...
Loading di/module_transformer transformers...
Unable to spawn isolate: Unhandled exception:
Could not import "package:async/async.dart" from "package:$pub/serialize.dart": Failure getting http://localhost:34928/packages/async/async.dart:
  404 Not Found
null
```

Does anyone have recommendations on how to solve this dependency hell? Is the second error regarding the `async.dart` package perhaps because I'm using a newer version of the Dart SDK?

Comment: I think the error message is wrong. These versions exist. Perhaps pub.dartlang.org doesn't list them anymore when `pub` queries them. I'd create a bug report in https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dartlang-dart

Comment: The source for Angular 0.14.0 is https://github.com/dart-archive/angular.dart/blob/v0.14.0/pubspec.yaml in case you need access to it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @GünterZöchbauer. I've created a report to see what they say: https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dartlang-dart/issues/1660

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion in several bug reports [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dartlang-dart/issues/1660) and [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/1988) the conclusion is that the newer SDK packages using a newer version of `pub` relied on several dependencies that weren't able to match the requirements for Angular 0.14.1.

I went back and installed version 1.12.0 of the SDK which was from around the time that this developer left us and successfully compiled the site. We'll be upgrading in the future to avoid this but that solved this issue for now.